# C++. Работа с динамическим двухмерным массивом на указателях

Tags: c++, указатели, динамические-массивы

Здравствуйте, есть код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

void print(int ** m, unsigned rows, unsigned cols)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            cout << m[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}


int main()
{
    int ** m = new int *[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        m[i] = new  int[5];
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            m[i][j] = i + j;
            cout << m[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << "==========================" << endl;

    print(m, 5, 5);
    return 0;
}
```

Видно, что массив построен на указателях. При создании массива в `main()` он попутно и выводится, всё в порядке. А вот при выводе в методе `print`, выводится не корректная информацию.

Я понял, что когда в методе `print` я прошу вывести масcив используя индексы `i` и `j`, я использую указатели, и неверный вывод связен, скорее всего, с указанием указателя куда-то в небо, но почему так происходит? Прошу, пожалуйста, разъяснить - в чём заключается ошибка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не хотите заменить

```
for (int j = 0; i < cols; j++)
```

на

```
for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
```

?

[Смотрите сами](http://ideone.com/IFX6wO)

Comment: Помогло,извините, это только  кусочек кода, я случайно в другом месте изменил, спасибо.

Comment: Ну, если все работает - закрывайте вопрос, пометив ответ как принятый...